# Xcode crashes when loading. Unexpected API Failure? DVTFoundation? IDEAssertionHandler?

Tags: xcode

So I have spend the greater portion of today trying to figure this out, and I have officially hit a brick wall in every direction I could figure.

Here is the simplified version of my project:
I have a workspace with several projects.  When I build, every project creates a framework target that my main app is linked to.

I needed to add in another framework, but only one of my projects needed it-- not my main app.

So I created another project, and built the framework OK.  I was able to take this pre-built framework and shove it into my project and everything built and worked fine.

However, I had to change this approach for 2 reasons:
1) If I ever wanted to change the framework, I would have to open up a separate project, modify and build, then move that framework back over.
2) Now, I could normally settle with that, but when I tried building my app, errors were thrown because it did not like me including dynamically linked libraries that were included in my library.

SO.  I decided to move this entire new framework project over to my main project, as a subproject of another project.

Here is a diagram of what is going on (pardon my lack of paint skills):
[image]

When I did this, I started getting this error when I built:

```
    2014-09-30 15:16:02.135 xcodebuild[43026:561b]  DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-6245/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/TargetSnapshots/HelperClasses/XCProjectHeadermapCreationInfo.mm:684
    Details:  Assertion failed: err == CXError_Success && "unexpected API failure"
    Object:   <XCProjectHeadermapCreationInfo: 0x7fe10ec2e390>
    Method:   -createVFSWithMacroExpansionScope:
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe10f3ed7c0>{name = (null), num = 3}
    Hints: None
    Backtrace:
      0  0x000000010fa6f15a -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
      1  0x000000010fa6ebaf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      2  0x000000010fa6ee9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      3  0x000000010fa6ee00 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      4  0x00000001113c1287 -[XCProjectHeadermapCreationInfo createVFSWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
      5  0x000000011141f151 -[PBXBuildOperationContext constructVFSForSnapshot:withMacroExpansionScope:atPath:] (in DevToolsCore)
      6  0x000000011151942a -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
      7  0x00000001113f2c2a -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
      8  0x000000011141063a -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
      9  0x000000011140f1d8 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
     10  0x000000011146b770 -[XCBlockQueue _processNextBlockInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
     11  0x000000011146ba40 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
     12  0x00007fff94571dfb __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
     13  0x00007fff95807899 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
     14  0x00007fff9580772a _pthread_struct_init (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
     15  0x00007fff9580bfc9 thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
    Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
    Flowdock: Team Inbox notification sent successfully
    Flowdock: Chat notification sent successfully
    Finished: FAILURE
```

So I thought, maybe I should just move this subproject back out to the root workspace.  So I did that, and did all the linking, but found that I still got that same error.  I investigated the workspace, and noticed that the path to my new project was an absolute path.  So I changed it to a relative path, and then my xcode crashed.  Now, whenever I open XCode, it crashes immediately when it starts trying to index (within 5 seconds)

I have since then reverted my changes to the workspace, but it still crashes every time.  I deleted my /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folders, cleaned everything, and it still crashes.  Here is the crash log:

```
Crashed Thread:        14  Dispatch queue: <IDEBuildOperation:0x7fd96cf1d7a0:REfc>-builder-queue :: NSOperation 0x7fd96d97cad0 (QOS: UTILITY)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A1030
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-6257/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/TargetSnapshots/HelperClasses/XCProjectHeadermapCreationInfo.mm:684
Details:  Assertion failed: err == CXError_Success && "unexpected API failure"
Object:   <XCProjectHeadermapCreationInfo: 0x7fd96c6c4110>
Method:   -createVFSWithMacroExpansionScope:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd96b7fa550>{number = 11, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010c1dba7a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010af95b9f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010af95e8e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010af95df0 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000116260017 -[XCProjectHeadermapCreationInfo createVFSWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x00000001162bdee1 -[PBXBuildOperationContext constructVFSForSnapshot:withMacroExpansionScope:atPath:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x00000001163b81ba -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00000001162919ba -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x00000001162af3ca -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x00000001162adf68 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x000000011624676b -[PBXTarget(XCBuildables) buildWillStartForBuilder:buildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore)
 11  0x0000000116439d52 -[Xcode3TargetBuildableSnapshot buildForBuilderWillStart:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x000000010b92eeac -[IDEBuildableSnapshot performBuildForBuilder:buildCommand:buildOnlyTheseFiles:] (in IDEFoundation)
 13  0x000000010b92e5cd -[IDEBuilder main] (in IDEFoundation)
 14  0x00007fff912be87c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 15  0x00007fff912be483 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 16  0x00007fff8cdecc13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff8cdf0365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18  0x00007fff8cdf1ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19  0x00007fff8cdef6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 20  0x00007fff8cdfdfe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 21  0x00007fff917236cb _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 22  0x00007fff917214a1 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
err == CXError_Success && "unexpected API failure"
```

I noticed the error was the same as previously when it wouldn't build.  I have tried cleaning everything I could, and I am on a previous commit that did not have this problem, for sure.   I have no idea why I was failing to build, and now why I'm perpetually crashing.  I am on Xcode 6.1 beta, I already tried reinstalling, installing Xcode 6, and installing Xcode 5 and I still get the same problem.  There is nothing on google I could find about any of these errors, and I am officially at a very thick brick wall.

If anybody could toss me some info or if they recognize anything here; I mostly just want to be able to use Xcode again

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing up my old questions-- this was a while ago but as it turns out the workspace just did not like me adding any new projects into it. I had to revert those changes and inevitably I made the switch to cocoapods and I haven't had any problems since

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the derived data folder fixed this crash in my case.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Comment: Can't confirm this works for me because this was a long time ago, but definitely something worth trying for anyone who stumbled across this thread